# Analysis from inertial frame

Tags: rotational-dynamics, inertial-frames

Assume there is a smooth table surface which turning about it's axis with angular velocity $\omega$ . A groove is also present which has a particle in it with mass $m$.

If we do analysis from a non internal frame of moment, let's say the particle itself, we see the normal forces due to walls cancel out and there's only centrifugal force which provides velocity. Centripetal forces can't be present as there's no source like frictional force.

But when i try to analyse this from inertial frame of reference, i can't find any acceleration as there would be no centrifugal force too

How can I justify the particle to be moving along the groove in that case ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What real force causes outward acceleration in rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/739295/)

Comment: Can you justify the material of the table top accelerating inward?

Comment: @BowlOfRed yes, thank you. I was going through a book, the author however assumed the normal forces from the walls of the grooves cancelling each other, maybe it's for convience.

Comment: @DJohnM from what i understand that shouldn't happen as there's no centripetal force acting to accelerate the body towards the center of rotation